# Unknown error sourcing a script containing 'typeset -r' wrapped in command substitution

Tags: ksh, readonly, typeset

I wish to source a script, print the value of a variable this script defines, and then have this value be assigned to a variable on the command line with command substitution wrapping the source/print commands.  This works on ksh88 but not on ksh93 and I am wondering why.

```
$ cat typeset_err.ksh
#!/bin/ksh
unset _typeset_var
typeset -i -r _typeset_var=1
DIR=init # this is the variable I want to print
```

When run on ksh88 (in this case, an AIX 6.1 box), the output is as follows:

```
$ A=$(. ./typeset_err.ksh; print $DIR)
$ echo $A
init
```

When run on ksh93 (in this case, a Linux machine), the output is as follows:

```
$ A=$(. ./typeset_err.ksh; print $DIR)
-ksh: _typeset_var: is read only
$ print $A
```

($A is undefined)

The above is just an example script.  The actual thing I wish to accomplish is to source a script that sets values to many variables, so that I can print just one of its values, e.g. `$DIR`, and have `$A` equal that value.  I do not know in advance the value of `$DIR`, but I need to copy files to `$DIR` during execution of a different batch script.  Therefore the idea I had was to source the script in order to define its variables, print the one I wanted, then have that print's output be assigned to another variable via `$(...)` syntax.  Admittedly a bit of a hack, but I don't want to source the entire sub-script in the batch script's environment because I only need one of its variables.

The typeset -r code in the beginning is the error.  The script I'm sourcing contains this in order to provide a semaphore of sorts--to prevent the script from being sourced more than once in the environment.  (There is an if statement in the real script that checks for `_typeset_var = 1`, and exits if it is already set.)  So I know I can take this out and get `$DIR` to print fine, but the constraints of the problem include keeping the `typeset -i -r`.

In the example script I put an `unset` in first, to ensure `_typeset_var` isn't already defined.  By the way I do know that it is not possible to unset a `typeset -r` variable, according to ksh93's man page for ksh.

There are ways to code around this error.  The favorite now is to not use typeset, but just set the semaphore without typeset (e.g. `_typeset_var=1`), but the error with the code as-is remains as a curiosity to me, and I want to see if anyone can explain why this is happening.

By the way, another idea I abandoned was to `grep` the variable I need out of its containing script, then print that one variable for `$A` to be set to; however, the variable (`$DIR` in the example above) might be set to another variable's value (e.g. `DIR=$dom/init`), and that other variable might be defined earlier in the script; therefore, I need to source the entire script to make sure I all variables are defined so that `$DIR` is correctly defined when sourcing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me in ksh93 (Version JM 93t+ 2009-05-01). If I do this, though:

```
$ . ./typeset_err.ksh
$ A=$(. ./typeset_err.ksh; print $DIR)
-ksh: _typeset_var: is read only
```

So it may be that you're getting that variable `typeset -r` in the current environment somehow.

Comment: @Bernard: Repeated calls for me print "init" each time.

Comment: Apologies for never following-up on this with certitude.  I revisited it again and in my simple example on both ksh88 and ksh93 it works.  But if I source the script first and then run it, on both ksh88 and ksh93 shells it fails:  I think therefore Dennis' hypothesis was correct, which was that I had sourced the script ahead of time and didn't realize it.  I was so sure I hadn't done that at the time!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
A=$(ksh -c "./typeset_err.ksh && print \$DIR")
```

or

```
A=$(env -i ksh -c "./typeset_err.ksh && print \$DIR")
```

Comment: Both of these calls do not cause error but produce an empty $A.  If I set A to something ahead of time and run either of these commands, $A ends up blank.